# Proof of Lemma 7.1 Bonsall and Duncan

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

In the proof of [Lemma 1 in section 7](https://books.google.com/books?id=5yvzCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA32) (A functional calculus for single Banach algebra element) of the book Complete normed algebras by Bonsall and Duncan, the last line says 
$$\phi\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial E} {(z-a)}^{-1} dz\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial E} h(z) dz$$ 
Can anyone tell what allows the functional $\phi$ to go inside the integral?

Comment: What is the relation between $\phi$ and $h$?

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta $h(z)=\phi({(z-a)}^{-1})$ for $z$ belonging to the resolvant set of $a$.

Comment: This is part of the definition of the vector-valued integral. (I forget exactly how Bonsall and Duncan set this up, but since the integrand is continuous on a neighbourhood of the contour, an adaptation of the Riemann integral should be sufficient.)